# qt any model\class for acessing windows registry

Tags: windows, qt, model-view-controller

I need to write regedit basic analog.
I want to use Qt. Any suggestions how i can get acess to the windows regisrty.
Maybe somebody seen class\model to work with Windows registry in Qt?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the [Qt Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsettings.html#accessing-the-windows-registry-directly), especially QSettings class.

Answer (score 0):

This is a piece of code which is used in my project. I hope it can help a lot.

```
/* write */
QSettings settings(QSettings::NativeFormat, QSettings::UserScope, "myCompany", "mySoftware");
settings.setValue("language", "en_US");
settings.sync();

/* read */
QSettings settings(QSettings::NativeFormat, QSettings::UserScope, "myCompany", "mySoftware");
QString language = settings.value("language", "en_US").toString();
```

The `language` key is stored in as

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\myCompany\mySoftware]
"language" = "en_US"
```